# Imagick installed but not loaded from apache?

Tags: php, apache

I am a bit confused. If I run a script it works both from php-built-in server and from console.

```
$img = new Imagick();
var_dump($img);
```

But if I run

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Apache do not see imagick. I use it in a Symfony application that sometimes return this error log:

`[2016-10-27 12:03:30] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "Imagick" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?" at /Volumes/Sviluppo/bitbucket.org/.../.../vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Imagick/Imagine.php line 39 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ClassNotFoundException(code: 0): Attempted to load class \"Imagick\" from the global namespace.\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement? at /Volumes/Sviluppo/bitbucket.org/.../.../vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Imagick/Imagine.php:39)"} []`

I wondered in imagick.ini file

```
$ php -i | grep ini | grep ima
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini,
```

that contains

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini
[imagick]
extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-imagick/imagick.so"
```

File exists!!!

PHP Version from cli is

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.12 (cli) (built: Oct 14 2016 09:55:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

But `phpinfo()` show me 7.0.11.

Finally, ... configuration loaded is php5 configuration. LOL. How can I move all my php to the same version?

[image: phpinfo output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does php -v on the command line still show my old version?**

> php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but
>   installs everything in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is
>   therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.

You can also adjust your PATH do include that directory, eg. write into your ~/.profile file the following

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

**Included extensions**

> bcmath bz2 calendar Core ctype curl date dom dtrace ereg exif fileinfo
>   filter ftp gd gettext hash iconv imap intl json ldap libxml mbstring
>   mcrypt memcache memcached mhash mongo mssql mysql mysqli mysqlnd OAuth
>   odbc openssl pcntl pcre PDO pdo_dblib pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite
>   pgsql Phar posix Reflection session shmop SimpleXML soap sockets solr
>   SPL SQLite sqlite3 standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy tokenizer
>   wddx xdebug xhprof xml xmlreader xmlrpc xmlwriter xsl zip zlib Xdebug
>
> available but disabled by default: apc, xslcache, twig, uploadprogress

Consider reading the documentation @ https://php-osx.liip.ch/

Comment: Do you want both versions of php, `php-osx` ( which is the older one ) could be uninstalled if you're not using it now. If you want to create the export path you can create it by doing `touch ~/.profile`, then edit it and include the export. If you already have `~/.bash_profile` you can also put it there I suppose.